# Convert string into float python properly

Tags: python

I am trying to convert the following string into float: `u'"0.5"'` but it seems that it does not work. I am trying to use `float(str1)` and I am receiving the following error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: "0.5"
```

It seems is the way that I have stored the string. But how can I convert it into a float properly?

Comment: Don't you need to remove the rabbit's ears yourself?

Comment: `float(str1.strip('"'))`

Comment: `float(ast.literal_eval(u'"0.5"'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to convert the  `" "` to float, which isn't possible.

This is a step by step code of what you should do :

```
unicode_value = u'"0.5"'

string_value = str(unicode_value)

float_value = float(string_value.strip('"'))

print float_value
```

This works without import, but you might as well use the other solution provided before by Shivkumar Kondi.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
import ast

a = u'"0.5"'
print a,type(a)

b = ast.literal_eval(a)
print b,type(b)

c = float(b)
print c,type(c)
```

Output :

```
"0.5" <type 'unicode'>
0.5 <type 'str'>
0.5 <type 'float'>
```